# What is the best way to learn design patterns as a student

Tags: design-patterns

I am a student who currently learning design patterns. One of the major problems I faced when I started learning design patterns is forgetting the pattern immediately. Even though its crystal clear when I studying the pattern, after a few days I forget how the pattern works.

As I guess the reason for that is, not practical usage of the pattern. When it comes to learning algorithms, I can just write code two, three times, and do some exercises in Hackerrank of CodeChef. But when it comes to design patterns, even I write the code, it's just disappearing from my mind.

Is this a common thing and do I have to stay patiently, and when I get a job and start working on a big codebase, and when I got to implement and learn actual use cases of design patterns, I will gradually learn design patterns or is it just I can't remember the patters?

Is there any recommended way to practice design patterns. I mean I can write the codes, and it's crystal clear at the moment I learn the pattern. But after a few days, it's just disappearing.

So, should I wait patiently or should pay more attention to remember the patterns?

Comment: wonder if you read what tag [tag:learning] says, "OFF TOPIC QUESTIONS ARE NOT SUPPORTED..."

Comment: Should I learn my tools, or hope that I never have to use them? Not that you can learn every tool out there, but if you draw a line in the sand and say, nope done my learning. Then you will fail and fail hard as a software developer. Our job is 100% about learning. So how about going on a code tour and playing spot that design pattern. Double points if you can spot it used well, and used poorly.

Comment: @Kain0_0 Actually I am asking is it a common behavior that learning design pattern is not similar to learning an algorithm. I definitely need to learn design patterns. I just want to know should I change my learning method? I am trying to remember how the pattern works.But it is not similar to learn an algorithm?

Comment: An off-topic question does not become magically on-topic by removing a tag. The idea is that people read it and get the message not to ask such questions here in the first place. But FWIW, the answer to *"when I get a job and start working on a big codebase, and when I got to implement and learn actual use cases of design patterns, will I gradually learn design patterns"* is YES, exactly that way.

Comment: @DocBrown what platform you suggest to ask such questions :(

Comment: The only place within the SE network I know where these kind of questions are welcome is the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DocBrown that would help. thank you so much!!!

Comment: Learning anything is similar to only itself. Otherwise you have already learnt it. As for a strategy on learning, that depends on what kind of learner you are. People are readers, listenners, doers, observers. And that changes depend on the actual topic. Appears that with coding you are doer, but as for learning about abstracted design? I've no clue what you are. Obviously your current method doesn't work. Try a method that suits a different style of learning. Find a lecture, Read a text book, Look for examples (in real code), implement the pattern in several languages. Just do something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design patterns are primarily a communication tool. They make it easier to discuss common solutions to common problems with other software engineers.

From that perspective, as a student you should learn about design patterns so that you know where to look for the details when people tell you that design pattern X (e.g. the Composite pattern) is being used or should be used somewhere.

As your experience grows, you may start to recognize the patterns in the designs/code you see without them being pointed out or you might even start to recognize where the patterns should be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with design patterns the same thing you do with algorithms. When I was a student, instad reading them from professor slides, I've started little plain java projects to implement them. For each of them I read which problem they can solve and I figure out a situation where they can be used whithin a specific, fictional context....for instance, think about you are writing a UI Library

- **Factory**: Creates objects hiding to the client the process to create them

*I have few controls (a button, a checkbox, a textField) and I need to offer library users a way to instantiate them, but they have to be injected with low level stuff that users should never know*

- **Abstract Factory** : You need a factory but there are many different versions of the same object to create according with a context

*I want to extend the previous library offering a predefined set of themes. Every control can be created in "dark" "light" or "classic" mode*

- **Composite** : Defines a Hierarchy of models in a tree-like structure in a way that you *can propagate behaviours on a subtree of the entire structure

*Now that I can instantiate controls, I want to put a panel system in my library. Each Panel can contain another panel or a control, that cannot contain anything else*

---

You can continue this exercise. Address each implementation separately for more clarity or build a "real fake" UI library. Then you can delete all and restart with another context.  A digital twin for a a complex industrial equipment, a "second life"-like game and whetever your imagination can create.....Because, well, I'm sorry to say to you that in your career you will implement design patterns not so often (frameworks do that for you) but you will often use your imagination to use them

Answer (score -1):

Personally I have troubles remembering the design patterns (there are quite a lot) but when I am coding sometimes I feel like my code looks like something I already know (architecture-wise), I then look at the list of design patterns and see if my code fits in one.

The solution might not be remembering them all but instead knowing approximately what they look like and have a cheat-sheet to help you when you think one can be used.